# Why is my regex failing in shell script although it is working in jregex?

Tags: java, regex, bash, shell

I have written this simple script for matching in shell script

```
file_name="xyz_abc_diagnostics.wifi2.2015-07-30.12-30-52.tar.gz"
chk_regex=".*\.\d+\-\d+\-\d+\.\d+\-\d+\-\d+.*"
if [[ "$file_name" =~ $chk_regex  ]];then
echo "in obs regex"
else
echo "dont triggered"
fi
```

I have checked this regex in java and here it is working fine.
my syntax is right because when i use

```
.*
```

it is working fine.
For shell script regex testing i have use this site
http://regexraptor.net/ to check it also don't matching but in https://regex101.com/ which uses java regex it matches.
I am not able to understand why it is failing in shell script.
Is there any difference in shell script regex?If yes then please suggest me what changes i have to make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is wrong to assume that all flavours of regex are the same. In this case, `\d` is not supported by bash regular expressions. You should change your regex to this:

```
chk_regex='\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+'
```

Of course, this assumes that when you say `\d` you don't require anything more than the digits from 0 to 9, as opposed to anything considered to be a digit in your locale. If you want to also match characters outside this range, then `[[:digit:]]` is probably what you want, instead of `[0-9]`.

If you don't require parameter expansion, it's generally a good habit to use `'` rather than `"`.

I have also removed the leading and trailing `.*` (as they don't do anything useful) and un-escaped the `-` (thanks for the comment gniourf_gniourf).

Working example:

```
$ file_name="xyz_abc_diagnostics.wifi2.2015-07-30.12-30-52.tar.gz"
$ chk_regex='\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+'
$ if [[ "$file_name" =~ $chk_regex  ]];then
> echo "in obs regex"
> else
> echo "dont triggered"
> fi
in obs regex
```

As you can see, the pattern matches, so the `if` branch is taken.

---

As mentioned in the comments, you can use globs to match this pattern as well:

```
[[ $file_name = *.+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])-+([‌​[:digit:]])* ]]
```

Granted, it's longer to write but globs may be useful if you wanted to loop through files matching this pattern, for example:

```
for archive in *.+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]]).+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])-+([‌​[:digit:]])*
do
    # some stuff
done
```

Note that in the example containing a loop (and in both examples on older versions of bash) you will need to enable extended globs using `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Now thinking about it, the glob looks longer and awkward, but you can use a variable to hold some parts of it: `ds=+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])-+([[:digit:]])` and then `[[ $file_name = *.$ds.$ds* ]]`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I was considering the same, although I guess at that point you're swapping one line for two. I'll leave the decision up to the OP :)

Comment: You also need `shopt -s extglob` in some versions of `bash`. I can never remember when that became the default inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @chepner `[[ ... ]]` is parsed as an extended glob since 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix, use `[0-9]` class instead of a `\d` and use `{2}` limiting quantifier to make it shorter (and really, the leading/trailing `.*` are useless since you are not using the matched string, just check for presence):

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name="xyz_abc_diagnostics.wifi2.2015-07-30.12-30-52.tar.gz"
chk_regex="(\.[0-9]+(-[0-9]+){2}){2}"
if [[ "$file_name" =~ $chk_regex  ]];then
echo "in obs regex"
else
echo "dont triggered"
fi
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/SewifC)

Result: `in obs regex`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thank you. I still wonder why IDEONE showed the right message when using `$`-prepended variable names.

Comment: Because both variables were unset (so expanded to the empty string), and the test boiled down to: `[[ '' =~ '' ]]` which is true. Try it: `[[ "$nonexistent" =~ $nonexistent ]] && echo yes`.